# Cant access the instances in a class error code while initialising

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Every time I try to initialise a kivy screen I always receive an error even tho I have researched and it shows that im doing it the proper way. I want to access the instances from my    `ProjectListScreen class` , ive initialised the instances to None but initialising the screen into the ApplyPage is not working, I tried to instantiate the class using Factory into my `ApplyPage class`  but it still does not return the value of the instance. Below is my code and after that is the traceback when I try to initialise the screen class. I would appreciate any help. please ive been struggling with this all day.

```
class ProjectListScreen(Screen):
    project_list = ObjectProperty(None)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ProjectListScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.thelocalId = None
        self.placementtext = None


    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        placements = database.child("placements").get()
        placementslist = placements.val()
        placementslist.items()
        for key, value in placementslist.items():
            self.key = key
            key_list = []
            key_list.append(key)
            for key in key_list:
                name = database.child("placements").child(str(key)).child("placement name").get()
                description = database.child("placements").child(str(key)).child("placement description").get()
                location = database.child("placements").child(str(key)).child("placement location").get()
                date = database.child("placements").child(str(key)).child("placement date").get()
                price = database.child("placements").child(str(key)).child("placement price").get()
                thelocalId = database.child("placements").child(str(key)).child("localId").get()
                self.thelocalId = thelocalId.val()
                self.project_list.adapter.data.extend([ "\n" + "\n" + str(name.val()) + '\n' + str(description.val()) + "\n" + str(location.val()) + '\n' + str(date.val()) + '\n' + '\n' + str(price.val())])

    def gettext(self):
        self.placementtext = self.project_list.adapter.selection[0].text

class ApplyPage(Screen):
    projectlistscreen = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, projectlistscreen, **kwargs):
        super(ApplyPage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.projectlistscreen = projectlistscreen
        self.yes = Button(text="Yes", font_size = 20, font_name= "fonts/Qanelas-Heavy.otf", background_color = (0.082, 0.549, 0.984, 1.0), background_normal= '', pos_hint = {"x":0.1,"y":0.05}, size_hint= [0.2, 0.1])
        self.add_widget(self.yes)
        self.no = Button(text="No", font_size= 20, font_name= "fonts/Qanelas-Heavy.otf", background_color = (0.082, 0.549, 0.984, 1.0), background_normal= '', pos_hint = {"x":0.7, "y":0.05}, size_hint= [0.2, 0.1])
        self.no.bind(on_pressed=self.nopressed)
        self.add_widget(self.no)

    def nopressed(self, instance):
        sm.current = "placements"

class MyApp(App):
    refresh_token_file = "refresh_token.txt"
    members_list = "members_list.txt"





    def build(self):
        self.refresh_token_file = self.user_data_dir + self.refresh_token_file
        self.thefirebase = MyFireBase()



        return sm

projectlistscreen = ProjectListScreen()
wm = WindowManager()
wm.add_widget(ApplyPage(projectlistscreen=projectlistscreen))

sm = Builder.load_file("kivy.kv")
```

kivy file

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
#: import mainfile mainfile
#: import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter
#: import ListItemButton kivy.uix.listview.ListItemButton
#: import FileChooserIconView kivy.uix.filechooser.FileChooserIconView



WindowManager:
    id: window manager
    ApplyPage:
        id: applyingpage
        name: "applyingpage"
    ProjectListScreen:
        id: project_list_screen
        name: "project_list_screen"

<ApplyPage>:

    name: "applyingpage"

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<ProjectListScreen>:

    project_list: project_list_view

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size


    Image:
        source: "icons/m.png"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.95}



    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.3, "center_y": 0.3}

        ListView:
            id: project_list_view
            adapter:
                ListAdapter(data=[], cls = mainfile.ProjectListButton)
```

Below is my traceback

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/temitayoadefemi/PycharmProjects/test5/mainfile.py", line 836, in <module>
     sm = Builder.load_file("kivy.kv")
   File "/Users/temitayoadefemi/PycharmProjects/test5/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 301, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "/Users/temitayoadefemi/PycharmProjects/test5/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 368, in load_string
     parser = Parser(content=string, filename=fn)
   File "/Users/temitayoadefemi/PycharmProjects/test5/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 392, in __init__
     self.parse(content)
   File "/Users/temitayoadefemi/PycharmProjects/test5/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 498, in parse
     self.execute_directives()
   File "/Users/temitayoadefemi/PycharmProjects/test5/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 462, in execute_directives
     mod = __import__(package)
   File "/Users/temitayoadefemi/PycharmProjects/test5/mainfile.py", line 836, in <module>
     sm = Builder.load_file("kivy.kv")
   File "/Users/temitayoadefemi/PycharmProjects/test5/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 301, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "/Users/temitayoadefemi/PycharmProjects/test5/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 400, in load_string
     self._apply_rule(widget, parser.root, parser.root)
   File "/Users/temitayoadefemi/PycharmProjects/test5/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 582, in _apply_rule
     child = cls(__no_builder=True)
 TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'projectlistscreen'
```

New error code

```
File "/Users/temitayoadefemi/PycharmProjects/test5/mainfile.py", line 834, in <module>
     wm.add_widget(ApplyPage(projectlistscreen))
 TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

If anybody could identify what im getting wrong on why the screen isnt initialising. thank you

Comment: Maybe `wm.add_widget(ApplyPage(projectlistscreen))` is working?

Comment: The error message mentions the `kivy.kv` file, but you have not posted that file.

Comment: @noEmbryo tried both of them and it still doesn't work

Comment: @JohnAnderson posted it, but my kivy file is pretty standard I don't know what could possibly be wrong with it

Comment: Can you show the child of the App class? Is WindowsManager a screen manager? If so - you have 'wm' instance, one defined in kv file and one in 'nopressed' method called sm like it's global variable. ScreenManager should be root (returned by build method) and you don't need to initiate it everywhere.

Comment: @Lothric ive put my app class in the edit, the 'nopressed' method was a mistake, ive removed it now

Comment: @JohnAnderson any ideas  ?

Comment: You continue to make the same errors, which indicates to me that you don't have a firm grasp of Python and Kivy. My suggestion is for you to so some studying. In particular, you should review [Defining Functions](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) and [the kivy language](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#module-kivy.lang). Pay particular attention to the discussion of `root widgets` in the `kivy` documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The `__init__()` method of your `ApplyPage` class requires the positional parameter `projectlistscreen`. When the `kv` file is loaded and the `ApplyPage:` is encountered, that `__init__()` method is called without the required `projectlistscreen` parameter. I suggest modifying that `__init__()` method to make the `projectlistscreen` a `kwarg` parameter as:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.projectlistscreen = kwargs.pop('projectlistscreen', None)
    super(ApplyPage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.yes = Button(text="Yes", font_size = 20, font_name= "fonts/Qanelas-Heavy.otf", background_color = (0.082, 0.549, 0.984, 1.0), background_normal= '', pos_hint = {"x":0.1,"y":0.05}, size_hint= [0.2, 0.1])
    self.add_widget(self.yes)
    self.no = Button(text="No", font_size= 20, font_name= "fonts/Qanelas-Heavy.otf", background_color = (0.082, 0.549, 0.984, 1.0), background_normal= '', pos_hint = {"x":0.7, "y":0.05}, size_hint= [0.2, 0.1])
    self.no.bind(on_pressed=self.nopressed)
    self.add_widget(self.no)
```

Also, I recognize your code from previous questions, and you are again making the same errors that I pointed out in earlier posts. Your code:

```
projectlistscreen = ProjectListScreen()
wm = WindowManager()
wm.add_widget(ApplyPage(projectlistscreen=projectlistscreen))
```

is creating a `ProjectListScreen`, a `WindowManager`, and an `ApplyPage`. None of which are actually used.

The code:

```
sm = Builder.load_file("kivy.kv")
```

builds the same `Widgets` as above, but these are actually used, since `sm` is returned by your `build()` method.

Comment: Thank you but can you show me another way to initialise without using this code `wm.add_widget(ApplyPage(projectlistscreen=projectlistscreen))`, I cant use Factory cause it only instantiates and I don't know any other method

Comment: the changes showed a new error, ive edited the question to show it. I would appreciate if you could look into it. if you need an MRE ill provide

Answer (score 0):

I would delete that thing from .kv file

```
WindowManager:
    id: window manager
    ApplyPage:
        id: applyingpage
        name: "applyingpage"
    ProjectListScreen:
        id: project_list_screen
        name: "project_list_screen"
```

And delete that from Python

```
wm = WindowManager()
wm.add_widget(ApplyPage(projectlistscreen=projectlistscreen))

sm = Builder.load_file("kivy.kv")
```

And delete that from ApplyPage class

```
def nopressed(self, instance):
        sm.current = "placements"
```

All you need is this:

```
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(WindowManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class MyApp(App):
    ...

    def build(self):
        self.refresh_token_file = self.user_data_dir + self.refresh_token_file
        self.thefirebase = MyFireBase()

        # I think you will need these objects later, so better to do it accessable for the whole class
        self.sm = WindowManager()
        self.pls = ProjectListScreen()
        self.applypage = ApplyPage(self.pls)

        # then add that screens to screen manager (it's even more simple than to do it in .kv)
        self.sm.add_widget(self.pls)
        self.sm.add_widget(self.applypage)
        return self.sm

    # if you need a transition to another screen, you can create method here
    def toapplypage(self):
        self.sm.transition.direction = 'left'
        self.sm.current = "applyingpage"
```

You can use methods to change screen in other classes but you need to send there the object you created in build method. So calling that methods would be like:

```
# it's only an example!
self.applypage.nopressed(self.sm)
```

And don't forget to write the name of the ProjectListScreen class in .kv file.